# How I can disable csrf token for some controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, csrf-token

In my web application csrf token work fine. But I want to disable that for API call which API call from my android app. I am using another authentication for my API. Please tell me how I can disable csrf token for my all function of the API controller. I tried to add access in my controller as the header but it is not working. Please help me.

```
public function __construct() {
    
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow- Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you want to disable CSRF feature just in the controller, you can change the config value of "csrf_protection" via `$this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', false);` in  constructor method.

Another and best way will be by adding paths in the config file to exclude from CSRF checks

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('api/person/add');
```

For more information look at [CI3 CSRF](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf)

Comment: Thanks for your response...it works fine. But If I want to disable csrf for all controller in one folder. Then this process is correct or not?

Comment: You can use either one on them

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter4 , goto `Config/Filters.php` and add

```
'csrf' => ['except' => ['Admin/index','Dashboard/index']],
```

in the **public $globals** array

This will exclude csrf checking for the pages Admin/index and Dashboard/index